# How to return string "test" and I'm using ?? operator

Tags: c#, operators

How do I return the string "test"?  I'm using `??` operator and method `GetStringValue` returns empty string.

Current value of `X` is "", but it's should be "test"?

```
var X = GetStringValue() ?? "test";

private static string GetStringValue()
{
   return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: `String.Empty` is not the same thing as `null`

Comment: `??` checks for `null`, change your method to return `null` and you will get the desired result. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: that's null but not empty